# file handling and size limitation

Tags: php, jquery, file, file-handling

I have a shoutbox that writes data on a single file name 'database.php' :

It automatically resets the file every something lines (I don't have the exact number of lines).

The question is how can I change the limitation in file writing.

```
$data = "$nick | $ipaddr | $timenow | $color | $avatar | $message\n";

    $handle = fopen(SHOUTBOX_DB,'a');
    fwrite($handle,$data);
    fclose($handle);
```

Comment: What the "limitation" you are referring to?

Comment: I am asking that ! I don't know why after for example 500 lines of entry the file resets itself.

Comment: Try to lock your file with [flock](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php). Your problem is may be due to excessive accesses simultaneous